# problems with aesthetic length geom_line shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, facet

I have data you can generate with:

```
set.seed(3)
dat.0<-as.data.frame(expand.grid(c("MATH","CHEM","BIOL"),c("Spring","Summer","Fall"),c(2016,2017,2018),0:17))
names(dat.0)<-c("SUBJ","SEM","YEAR","WEEK")
dat.0$MEET<-floor(runif(486,0,150))
```

I'm trying to make a shiny app that will display a line plot of the "MEET" series with "WEEK" on the x-axis colored by the "SUBJ" field.

outside of shiny the plot looks fine:

```
dat.0%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = WEEK,y = MEET,colour = SUBJ))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_path()+
  facet_grid(YEAR~SEM)
```

but when I use shiny to create the app, it spits out an error if I try to plot more than one series on the plot. What's more if you plot each of the series individually inside the app, you realize that no matter which "SUBJ" you select, it prints the same plot:

```
choices = levels(as.factor(dat.0$SUBJ))
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("STEM Tutoring App"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("SUBJ",
                  "Course Subject:",
                  choices = choices,
                  multiple = T,
                  selectize = T)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("linePlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$linePlot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$SUBJ)
    dat.0%>%
      ggplot(aes(x = WEEK,y = MEET,colour = input$SUBJ))+
      geom_point()+
      geom_path()+
      facet_grid(YEAR~SEM)})}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I know this is almost there, I just don't know how to make it looks good and functions the way you would expect.

Comment: It looks like you want to subset the data to the appropriate `SUBJ` and then plot that dataset with `colour = SUBJ`.  When you do `colour = input$SUBJ` you are mapping the aesthetic to a constant and not subsetting to only that group.  If you want all subjects plotted on a single plot you can skip the subsetting step all together and use `colour = SUBJ` to get different lines per group.

Comment: I mean sometimes I want to plot all subjects on the same plot. other times I only want math and bio, and still other times it would be nice to see only chemistry. I thought that was the point to having those input pieces. Do I have to call a different subset for all the possible combincations of subjects I could want on the plot?

Comment: You will want to make your dataset reactive, so it makes a subset of your chosen subjects.  This reactive dataset is what you will use in your plot.  I'd come at this by first working out example code outside of shiny.  Maybe something like `filter(p.01, SUBJ %in% c("MATH", "CHEM") %>% ggplot...`.  Then figure out how to make that take my `input` from the app.

Comment: OK. thank you that helps a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to this, as user @aosmith explains in the comments is that You need to make the data set react to user inputs by defining the subsetting parameters after the sidebar, within the renderPlot function, so you would put

```
server <- function(input,output) {

   output$linePlot<-renderPlot({
       req(input$SUBJ)

       plot.data <- dat.0 %>%
           dplyr::filter(SUBJ %in% input$SUBJ)

       plot.data %>%
           ggplot(aes(x = WEEK, y = MEET, colour = SUBJ)) +
           geom_point() +
           geom_path() +
           facet_grid(YEAR~SEM)
    })
}
```

subsetting based on user input was where I got confused. problem solved, though. thank you for the help!